# 'Bad Request' downloading some files in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http

I had some time off recently and thought it would be a neat exercise to see how quickly I could put together a working program to automatically retrieve '.torrent' files for me.  I'm aware there are existing solutions, but this was more of a programming exercise.

All was well, it ran, checked the sites for new torrents, and attempted to download them.  But this is where I'm running into a problem; one of the sites that I'm trying to download the .torrent file from is giving me a file containing this instead of the torrent file when I try to download it;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at forums.mvgroup.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

My first thought was maybe a broken link, so I went and successfully downloaded the file in my browser, so it's not a broken link.. My next thought is that maybe I'm not downloading the file correctly.. [This](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2469) is the example that I used, and [this](https://github.com/jeffWelling/tget/blob/0bfce6026d55cf0a509632abb0d306c79597d50f/lib/tget/main.rb#L96) is actual code that's doing the downloading in my program.

I have a sneaking suspicion this is going to turn out to be one of those brain-dead simple gotchas, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring it out.  Does anyone know why I'm getting a 400, or how to fix this?

Comment: How does the actual HTTP request look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A broken link should return a `404 Not Found` error. Because you can retrieve the file with a browser I see there are two other possible issues: Either you are missing handling redirects in your code that the browser handles automatically, or you are missing needed session IDs or cookies or some state value. Again, a browser will handle those but your code will not unless you write it in, or take advantage of the right gem.

The sample code you link to at http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2469 is rudimentary, but is not wired to follow redirects, which is what I suspect you need. I glanced at your code and it doesn't handle them either. The "Following Redirection" sample code in the [docs for `Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) shows how to do it.

Rather than write the code to retrieve the URL yourself, amounting to reinventing the wheel, I recommend using Ruby's [`Open::URI`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/1.9.2/frames), because it handles redirects automatically along with time-out retries. It's easy to use and a good work horse for those normal "get a URL" jobs.

If you want to have a gem that handles redirects and cookies and session IDs, look at [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/). It's a very good gem for general purpose tasks, though it is really designed for navigating web sites.

For more robust tasks, [Curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/) and [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) are good because they can handle multiple requests, though you'll need to write a bit more code for managing the files and navigating sites. For a file download they'd be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need a logging proxy in between, so you can see which bytes go over the wire.

If you use Eclipse, it has a http proxy available.  I believe it is part of the Eclipse Java EE download.

Comment: I do not know.  I believe if you can see exactly what goes over the wire you might be able to see what is wrong.

Comment: tcpdump or wireshark should be able to tell you.